# Matlab: How to crop an array in specified dimension iff from there on all values equal a specified value

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

In Matlab, im looking for a way to solve the following issue in an a bit more elegant way:
In an threedimensional array, on one dimension (i.e. time in my case), from some index on all values equal zero, e.g. the following example array a is 0 for an index of 3 for the second dimension  (i.e. `a(:,3:end,: == 0)`):

```
a(:,:,1) =

 1     1     0
 1     0     0
 1     0     0


a(:,:,2) =

 1     1     0
 1     0     0
 1     1     0


a(:,:,3) =

 1     1     0
 1     1     0
 1     1     0
```

[edit, was asked for expected outcome]

expected outcome is:

```
o(:,:,1) =

     1     1
     1     0
     1     0


o(:,:,2) =

     1     1
     1     0
     1     1


o(:,:,3) =

     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
```

now of course i could just check for each index in dimension 2, whether it actually is zero everywhere, which is what i'm doing right now, but i feel like there is some better way of solving this issue in matlab in some more elegant way (and possibly even for any multidimensional array). Thanks for helping!

Comment: so your expected output is....?

Comment: thanks for mentioning, edit now respects that issue

Comment: so you want to remove those same columns which have all zeros/other specific values?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Even more awesome would of course be a solution which solves this for arbitrary dimensionality.

Comment: I think your first sentence got chopped off somewhere, I can't make out what you're trying to achieve. Can you include your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function req = removeColwithSpecVal(a,spec_val)
  req=num2cell(a,[1 2]);     %Converting to cell keeping the order of rows & columns same  
  req=vertcat(req{:});       %Stacking multidimensional slices vertically
  ind= ~all(req==spec_val,1);%Finding logical indices of the required columns
  req = req(:,ind);          %The matrix after removal of the not required columns
  %Finding the size of the input matrix 'a'; stacking with 1 so that 
  %it is applicable on 1-D/2-D matrices as well
  sz =[size(a) 1];           
  %Finding the # of columns that the required multi-dimensional matrix will have
  sz(2)= numel(req)/prod([sz(1), sz(3:end)]);
  %Reshaping to the desired result
  req=reshape(permute(reshape(req.', sz(2),sz(1),[]),[2 1 3]),sz); 
end
```

**Sample Runs:**

```
%1-D Example
spec_val=5;
a=[1 4 5 2 5];
req = removeColwithSpecVal(a,spec_val)

req =

     1     4     2
```

```
%2-D Example
spec_val=0;
a=[1  1  0 ;
   1  0  0 ;
   1  0  0 ];
req = removeColwithSpecVal(a,spec_val)

req =
      1     1
      1     0
      1     0
```

```
%Your example (3-D)
spec_val=0;
a(:,:,1) = [1  1  0;
            1  0  0;
            1  0  0];
a(:,:,2) = [1  1  0;
            1  0  0;
            1  1  0];
a(:,:,3) = [1  1  0;
            1  1  0;
            1  1  0];
req = removeColwithSpecVal(a,spec_val)

req(:,:,1) =

     1     1
     1     0
     1     0


req(:,:,2) =

     1     1
     1     0
     1     1


req(:,:,3) =

     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
```

Also applicable on higher dimensional matrices.